# Annotation for mapping another Entity in Entity

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-mvc

My Director class has Array of Movie object inside it and I want to have a table for Director and another table for Movie, How can I handle that using Hibernate annotations in a way that just store reference for Movie in Director Table and reference for Director in Movie table?

I Also have Director object in each Movie object either.

Here is my Director Class:

```
public class Director {

    private String id;

    private String name;

    private String location;

    private Movie[] movies;
    //setter and getter ...
}
```

Here is my Movie class:

```
public class Movie {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private double rate;
    private int numberOfRates;
    private Category[] categories;
    private String director;
    private int duration;
    private String photoUrl;
    //setter and getter ...
}
```

Comment: So you want to have a _many-to-many_ mapping between movies and directors? One movie can have many directors and any director can appear in many movies?

Comment: Putting Hibernate and java aside, how do you want those tables to look like? Because the way you described it it's a one to one mapping (director has only one movie, and a movie has only one director), and I doubt that's what you want.

Comment: @MickMnemonic not exactly, each movie has only one director and each director has array of movies so I think it is one to many

Comment: @TomaszNocoń no, as I wrote in code, director has array of movies

Comment: so it seems like you have many-to-one relationship between movie and the director; so you might want to store foregin key to director table at movie's table. Take a look at the jointable annotation if you want to design your entities like above.

Comment: Well then you're gonna have to have a seperate table containing relations between the two.
The annotations you're looking for are OneToMany and ManyToOne.
You can read more about them [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations)
And you should use Collections instead of arrays.